# removeClass doesn't work on the second DIV tag

Tags: jquery

I am learning JQuery and writing a simple data validation for the two fields in
a HTML form:

```
<FORM name="addpost" id="addpost" method="post" action="/add">
    <TABLE border=0 width="100%">
        <TR>
            <TD>Topic</TD>
            <TD>       
                <DIV id="topic">
                    <INPUT type=text name="topic" id="topic" size="72" maxlength="108"/>
                </DIV>       
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Comments</TD>
            <TD>
                <DIV id="topiccontent">        
                    <TEXTAREA rows="12" cols="48" name="content" id="content">
                    </TEXTAREA>
                </DIV>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</FORM>
```

Here is the JQuery script for checking the data input from the form above:

```
$('#addpost').submit(function(){       
    if($('#topic').val()==""){
        $('#topic').addClass('hierror'); 
        return false;}
    else{$('#topic').removeClass('hierror');}

    if($('#topiccontent').val()==""){
        $('#topiccontent').addClass('hierror'); 
        return false;}
    else{$('#topiccontent').removeClass('hierror');}
});
```

Here is the CSS for the hierror class:

```
.hierror{border-style:solid; border-width:12px; border-color:#FF0000;}
```

The problem is that `('#topic').removeClass('hierror')` works but `('#topiccontent').removeClass('hierror')` doesn't.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things wrong about your markup:

Do not type HTML entities in uppercase (use `<div>` not `<DIV>`).

Each tag must have unique ID (so `div` and `input` need to have different IDs). In jQuery check `('#topic input').val()`, but then execute `('#topic').removeClass()`

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the general problems that @Konrad Garus is talking about, your particular problem is that your JS code is performing the validation by using  `.val()` on the `#topiccontent` element, which happens to be a `div`. Your `textarea` element, which is the one you want to perform the validation on, is named `content`.